# Retrieve column descriptions from SQL Server-linked table in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-tables

I am linking to tables in SQL Server from an MS Access front-end.  There are column descriptions for some of the tables in SQL Server that I would like to bring forward when I create the linked tables in Access.  Is there a way to get at the column descriptions programmatically?

(I know how to append the description to the linked tables, I just need help getting at the descriptions in the back end.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
DECLARE @TableName varchar(100)
SELECT @TableName = 'yourtablename'


-- This will determine if we're using version 9 (2005) of SQL Server, and execute code accordingly

IF CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as varchar),1,2), '.','') as int) >= 9
BEGIN
      -- This is a SQL 2005 machine
      SELECT  
            [Table Name] = OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id), 
            [Column Name] = c.name, 
            [Description] = ex.value  
      FROM  
            sys.columns c  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN  
            sys.extended_properties ex  
      ON  
            ex.major_id = c.object_id 
            AND ex.minor_id = c.column_id  
            AND ex.name = 'MS_Description'  
      WHERE  
            OBJECTPROPERTY(c.object_id, 'IsMsShipped')=0  
            AND OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = @TableName
      ORDER  
            BY OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id), c.column_id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      -- assume this is a SQL 2000
      SELECT 
            [Table Name] = i_s.TABLE_NAME, 
            [Column Name] = i_s.COLUMN_NAME, 
            [Description] = s.value 
      FROM 
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i_s 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            sysproperties s 
      ON 
            s.id = OBJECT_ID(i_s.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+i_s.TABLE_NAME) 
            AND s.smallid = i_s.ORDINAL_POSITION 
            AND s.name = 'MS_Description' 
      WHERE 
            OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(i_s.TABLE_SCHEMA+'.'+i_s.TABLE_NAME), 'IsMsShipped')=0 
            AND i_s.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
      ORDER BY
            i_s.TABLE_NAME, i_s.ORDINAL_POSITION 
END
```

Comment: Very nice.  I especially like the conditional that automatically switches between the correct property tables for 2005+ vs the earlier versions.

Comment: One quick bug fix.  The version check fails on SQL Server 2008 (`productversion == 10...`).  Since you are just grabbing the first character it is returning a version number of 1.  T-SQL is not my forte, but the following updated line works in both SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008:  `IF CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as varchar),1,2), '.','') as int) >= 9`  There may be a better approach than mine, though.

Comment: -1 - Exact copy and paste from http://robkennedy.com/2007/09/20/retrieving-column-descriptions-from-ms-sql/ with no attribution.

Comment: Sorry... I usually try to make sure I do that... Thanks